# How to assert a bad-initialized collection in visualStudio unitTesting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I wrote the following code:

```
[TestMethod]
//[ExpectedException(typeof(UriFormatException), "url should be well formatted.")]
public void FetchHtmlContent_badUrl_throwUriFormatException()
{
    HashSet<string> urls = new HashSet<string> { "ww.stackoverflow.com" };
    var contextManager = new ContentManager(urls);
    var content = contextManager.GetHtmlContent();
    Assert.IsTrue(content.ElementAt(0).Contains("threw an exception of type 'System.UriFormatException'"));
}
```

contextManager.GetHtmlContent() doesn't throw an exception,

but `content.ElementAt(0)` throws (as expected)

```
+       content.ElementAt(0)    'content.ElementAt(0)' threw an exception of type 'System.UriFormatException'   string {System.UriFormatException}
```

How can I verify content.ElementAt(0) throws this exception

(or should I verify this test some other way ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the responsibility of the `ContentManager.GetHtmlContent` method? If as name would indicate, retrieving HTML content from URL, then invalid url is *execution failure* scenario (method cannot do what it is supposed to). You have two choices:

- throw invalid uri Exception from `.GetHtmlContent` method (communicates well what happens, and follows [Microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))
- return `null` from `.GetHtmlContent` and deal with that later

Note that *returning null result* might also be used for a case when HTML content is indeed `null`, therefore I suggest throwing exception here. It states what happened in more clear way.

Your test might look like that:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(UriFormatException), "url should be well formatted.")]
public void GetHtmlContent_ThrowsInvalidUriException_WhenUriIsInBadFormat()
{
    HashSet<string> urls = new HashSet<string> { "ww.stackoverflow.com" };
    var contextManager = new ContentManager(urls);

    contextManager.GetHtmlContent();
}
```

Comment: But it returns `content` and not exception. Accessing ElementAt(0) throw exception

Comment: I'm using visualStudio unitTesting. There is no `Assert.That`

Comment: @EladBenda: is this class your, or some 3rd party? Can you (do you want to) change it? IMO, it would be more clear if that method would throw. Let me know if you cannot alter its behavior. *(I've updated test to match MS testing framework)*

Comment: @Elad you can use [`ExpectedExceptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx)